# Auth::check() in view always returns false

Tags: laravel-5

I am trying to display some content in a partial only to logged in users. The content is never displayed. Here is the bit of code:

```
  @if(Auth::check())
     <a href="{{ route('backend.blog.edit', $id) }}">
         Edit
     </a>
  @endif
```

The page that contains the partial is available to everyone; I only want to hide this one bit of content.
Can anyone point me in the right direction?

**Additional info**
This is part of a CMS system I am attempting to write. So, the controller is called via a service provider (RouteServiceProvider). I am pulling the routes based on a pages model. Here is the pertinent method:

```
  public function map(Router $router)
  {
    $this->mapWebRoutes($router);

    foreach (Page::all() as $page) {
        $router->get($page->uri, ['middleware' => 'web', 'as' => $page->name, function () use ($page, $router) {
            return $this->app->call('App\Http\Controllers\PageController@show', [
                'page' => $page,
                'parameters' => $router->current()->parameters()
            ]);
        }]);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Did you try auth()->check() instead of Auth::check()?

Comment: are you sure this controller is passed through `auth` middleware?

Comment: @MinaAbadir no. You may be onto my problem. How do I do that and still allow guests?

Comment: @RogerCreasy you are correct, I meant middleware `web`

Comment: Thanks. I tried adding the web middleware in my `RouteServiceProvider`. It still doesn't work..

Comment: @RogerCreasy can you post your routes file and the method from which this view is initiated

Comment: @jaysingkar I added my routeprovider. Should I call the web middleware in teh controller instead?

Comment: @RogerCreasy no, its look good, BTW where are you using `auth` middleware ?

Comment: Please double check your spelling of files and in your question - `RouteSrevicePRovider` is an obvious typo in your question wording. But assuming you aren't replicating typos in your actual code is a bad place to start in debugging.

Comment: Auth middleware is used on the backend. I need someone logged into the backend to see some links on the front-end

Comment: @Jonathan thanks. Good thought...I have a lazy pinky on the shift key :)

Comment: `Auth::check()` should be all you need. Did you actually load the laravel library with `php artisan make:auth` ?

Comment: @Jonathan not sure. How could I confirm?

Comment: The first step to using the auth library with laravel is to generate the required files with `php artisan make:auth`. If you haven't done this step, it might explain why you don't have `Auth` available to your view

Comment: I am using authentication on the backend, and it is working. Is it possible that the session is just not available on my frontend for some reason?

Comment: What resource did you read that lead you to defining your routes in `RouteServiceProvider`? I can understand that this may be your CMS approach to defining routes - but I'd like to see the info myself so I can cut it apart

Comment: It was on a TutsPlus how-to. So, it is paid content. I am only just beginning to understand how it functions. It is done this way so users can define pages. I am OK with taking it apart and define routes the usual Laravel way, if that is what would worjk best.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution

```
public function map(Router $router)
{   
    $this->mapApiRoutes();

    $this->mapWebRoutes();

    Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function ($router) {

    if (! app()->runningInConsole()) {
        foreach (ProductCategory::all() as $category) {
            $router->get($category->uri, ['as' => $category->name, function () use ($category, $router) {
                return $this->app->call(
                    'App\Http\Controllers\PageController@show', [
                    'category' => $category,
                    'parameters' => $router->current()->parameters()
                ]);
            }]);
        }
    }

    });

}
```

Comment: explain the solution a little more, so the OP can learn from it and not just copy-paste it.